# Sort List<Elements> with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, sorting

I have a List added to the model and showed in the JSP as a table.

I want to create some sort methods to order this table in a differents ways like many pages have. For example, one column is PublishDate, if the users click on the column header, the table must to be sort by this bean attribute (PublishDate). In the same way for more visited, more values... etc etc.

How can i sort the table using Ajax (with no page reload)

Answer (score 0):

try this plug in

http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

hope helps :)

Comment: Thanks Shiva, but that's don't solve my problem, because some sorting methods I need are not visibles columns, are attributes of my Bean but i don't show those elementes

Comment: so use ajax . like when we clicked on column header write ajax and send the column header in post return the values with query like ASC or DSC depends on the click.